# JDBC: safe row update when multiple requests

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Java RESTful API that uses JDBC with ComboPooledDataSource for connection pooling (http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), and a PreparedStatement that updates a row by incrementing a field:

```
public void update(int messageId) {

    String UPDATE_STM = "UPDATE table SET count_field = count_field +1 WHERE id=?";
    conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_STM );
    stm.setInt(1, messageId);
    stm.executeUpdate();
}
```

(I've omitted try/catch, and ConnectionManager.getConnection() gives me one of the available connections from the pool).
If my RESTful service receives two or more requests for update() method at the same time, am I granted that the count is updated correctly?
If not, how I should modify the code to avoid a wrong count update?

Comment: Make this class singleton and add syncronized to method declaration. But the best solution for increment values use database build in tools like sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use InnoDB**

As far as I can see, your Java code is thread-safe, it doesn't access or change any fields. All you have to worry about is the **UPDATE** action on the database side. I assume you are using MySQL, since you have tagged the question with `mysql` tag. MySql DBMS offers the *ACID* model, you need to set the database engine to `InnoDB` for that to work. For more details see this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html).

Comment: After i set db engine to InnoDB, how i should modify my java code for let it work?